# Raspberry as a separate box with Wi-Fi hotspot

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set my Raspberry Pi to a separate box with Wi-Fi access. I would be very happy if I could get a small box which can be access by any device with Wi-Fi capabilities with ssh, vncviewer.

I used the manual (http://raspberry-at-home.com/hotspot-wifi-access-point/) and at the end I got Raspberry Pi Wi-Fi Hotspot.
I can find it, connect ... but that's all. When I'm trying to connect with ssh or vncviewer no results. I can't even ping (it "hangs").
'ip neigh' gives the response REACHABLE.

My goal is to have a Raspberry box which can be the Wi-Fi hotspot and accessable with ssh and vncviewer without any additional network.
If somebody knows how-to reach this dream, help please! Any help will be highly appreciated!

Best regards
Vilis.

Please find below current settings:

**interfaces**:

```
auto lo
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/ipv4.nat
```

**hostapd.conf**

```
# Basic configuration

interface=wlan0
ssid=VK-wifi
channel=1
#bridge=br0

# WPA and WPA2 configuration

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=<SECRET PASS>
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Hardware configuration

driver=rtl871xdrv
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
device_name=RTL8192CU
manufacturer=Realtek
```

**iptable rules:**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Apr  6 17:04:48 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [58:4242]
:INPUT ACCEPT [58:4242]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [85:6230]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr  6 17:04:48 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Apr  6 17:04:48 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -f -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr  6 17:04:48 2015
```

Comment: So you are saying you need to convert your RPi onto a smart router&server?

Comment: I would like to get Wi-fi hostspot which can be used as a separate box (without cables or external network). Just to sign-in from any Wi-fi capable device and get access to Raspberry Pi using either ssh or vncviewer. The most important ability to get data from Raspberry Pi box without any cable.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded doing what you wanted to do
**interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 255.0.0.0
```

**hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=pi
channel=1
```

Install dnsmasq. It will give IPs to all devices that connect with your pi so you can communicate via ssh. 
**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.250,12h
no-resolv
```

Comment: You won't be able to connect to the internet, but you can still connect to the pi

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experions. I'll try definitely